Как использовать Laravel Basset (Backpack) совместно с nginx?
Я использую Laravel Backpack. Он в свою очередь использует Basset для поиска статики. Так вот, когда мое PHP приложение генерирует админ-панель, оно просит Basset найти для него статику. А внутри него происходит что-то вроде base_path('vendor/basset/...').
И запрос на nginx сервер выглядит следующим образом http//localhost/var/www/app/vendor/basset..., где var/www/app - базовая папка моего PHP приложения. Пришла сюда благодаря base_path.
И все мои ресурсы не найдены, потому что в nginx конфигурации root: var/www/app/public
... поэтому он не может найти нужную статику.
Спасибо заранее за помощь!

Так а в чем проблема добавить alias для nginx по нужному вам пути внутри location?

@DanielProtopopov потому что это костыль. Я решил эту проблему изменив параметр окружения в .env
